# EditText And Buttons in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-edittext, android-button

I have created custom `ListView` which is having two `TextViews`, Two `Buttons` and one `EditText`,

**My problem is:**

1) Edit text is **loosing control even after adding**  `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`

to root layout and beforeDescendants blocks onItemClick and onClick of buttons

2) If I add `android:descendantFocusability="BlocksDescendants"` in root layout then onItemClick of list and onClick of buttons start working but EditText become untouchable even after touching edittext keyboard doesnt show up.

Can anyone please guide me?

My Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_detail_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="textPersonName" >
            </EditText>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its more easy to understand question with code which you have tried.

Comment: you are not able to focus on edittext use this property                         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: Try replace this: android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" with this: android:focusable="false", android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: Haresh I have tried this but what happen is EditText is getting clicked but I whatever I am typing is not reflecting in EditText its loosing control

Answer (score 0):

I suggest try to implement custom listview for this we create a adapter in which we will create two layouts

Layout1)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout2)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="Button" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And in .java class create a custom adapter for listview
Test.java)

```
    public class Testttt extends Activity {
     ListView listView;
     CustomAdapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.direction);
    findId();
    executionMethod();
   }

 private void findId() {
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
  }

 private void executionMethod() {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

 class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public CustomAdapter(Context convertView) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater
                .from(getApplicationContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.qwerty, null);
        Button btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        EditText edt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        return view;
    }

   }

  }
```

It should be note that in customadapter class you can set functionality in particular item according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` under activity tag in which you have made list view