# Adding/removing edit text and a remove (X) on click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to android development.

I want to add EditText and a remove button ( X ) when they click on a button (called “contact”). So that there will be multiple contacts. On click of the remove button the corresponding added EditText with remove button should be disappeared.

It will be something like this,

————————— X

————————— X

————————— X

————————— X

```
 ———————
|contact|  
 ———————
```

If I use any Adapter, how to add the empty  EditText and a remove button ( X ).  If not any other better options?
Finally I need to get all the values entered in the EditText.

NOTE: On click of “contact” it should be adding EditText and a remove button ( X ).

Kindly give me a clear and simple way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320577/edittext-and-buttons-in-listview-android)

Comment: Refer the following questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663443/add-delete-option-with-dynamically-generated-edittext?noredirect=1&lq=1          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666301/android-dynamically-add-edittext-in-linearlayout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add delete option with dynamically generated editText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663443/add-delete-option-with-dynamically-generated-edittext)

Comment: @ Pier Giorgio Misley, I tried the solution given in the link, getView() method is not called.

Comment: @SARATHV I checked the link, I was looking for a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `LinearLayout`with `orientation` set to vertical. you can then create another layout with your`EditText`and `Button` and add them dynamically to the `LinearLayout` within the `onClick` method for contact button.

Do not forget to generate different IDs for your newly added views to be able to find them later

The X button will then just remove its parent from the layout

Comment: good.. dont' forget to accept the answer so other people can benefit too

Answer (score 1):

Create a `LinearLayout` and button. On the button click call the following method. Also, create a `List<EditText>` in your `onCreate` Method to track all added edittexts & retrieve texts later.

```
private void createNewEditText() {
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setMaxLines(1);
    editText.setSingleLine(true);
    editText.setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, VectorDrawableCompat.create(resources, R.drawable.ic_clear_black_24dp, null), null);
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override 
        Boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event) {
            val DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3
            val DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2
            val DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0
            val DRAWABLE_TOP = 1
            if (event.getRawX() >= (editText.right - editText.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].bounds.width())) {
                editTextList.remove(editText);
                parentLinearLayout.removeView(editText);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    })
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setText(voicetext);
    editTextList.add(editText);
    parentLinearLayout.addView(editText);
}
```